# Get data attribute of script tag?

Tags: javascript, script-tag

Say I've got the following script tag:

```
<script async data-id="p3PkBtuA" src="//example.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Within that `embed.js` file, how can I get the value of `data-id` attribute?

I'm trying to keep the `embed.js` file as light as possible, so ideally it wouldn't need to use some sort of javascript library.

Answer (score 55):

For modern browsers that support html5 you can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript) to get the current script element.

Otherwise, use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to select your script element by **id** or **attribute**.

Note that we don't use the `src` attribute because that can be fragile if you're delivering over a CDN or with differences between development and production environments.

**embed.js**

```
(function(){
    // We look for:
    //  A `script` element
    //  With a `data-id` attribute
    //  And a `data-name` attribute equal to "MyUniqueName"
    var me = document.querySelector('script[data-id][data-name="MyUniqueName"]');
    var id = me.getAttribute('data-id');
})();
```

**In the host html:**

```
<script async 
  data-id="p3PkBtuA" 
  data-name="MyUniqueName" 
  src="//example.com/embed.js">
</script>
```

This approcah has the downside that you couldn't successfully embed two identical scripts. This is a pretty rare case, but could happen.

Note that I would personally us `data-id` to select the script instead of passing data, and would place the unique data in a more descriptive tag:

```
<script async 
  data-id="MyUniqueName" 
  data-token="p3PkBtuA" 
  src="//example.com/embed.js">
</script>
```

which would let me use this following:

```
var token = document
  .querySelector('script[data-id="MyUniqueName"][data-token]')
  .getAttribute('data-token');
```

Answer (score 14):

### Use [currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Script tag :

```
<script async data-id="p3PkBtuA" data-foo ="bar" src="//example.com/example.js"></script>
```

In example.js file :

```
let id = document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-id');
let foo = document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-foo');  

console.log(id) // p3PkBtuA
console.log(foo) // bar
```

Comment: this is the best answer in my opinion; it even allows you to load the same script multiple times, changing the data-* tags each time. this really helps with reusability

Answer (score 9):

That `embed.js` is being rendered in the DOM, so you have full access to it. Eithergive it an `id` and use `document.getElementById` of `querySelctorAll` or `getElementsByTagName`

Within your `embed.js` you could have something like:

```
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for(var i = 0, l = scripts.length; i < l; i++){
    if(scripts[i].src === '//example.com/embed.js'){
      alert(scripts[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
      break;
    }
  }
```

You get the idea

Answer (score 3):

> Within that embed.js file, how can I get the value of data-id attribute?

You will have to parse the DOM and look for the corresponding `<script>` tag and then fetch the attributes from it. Take a look at the [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) which would allow you to retrieve all `<script>` elements on the current page. Then loop through the result array returned by this method, match the correct script element using the `src` attribute and then read the other attributes you are interested in.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var script = scripts[i];
    // you might consider using a regex here
    if (script.getAttribute('src') == '//example.com/embed.js') {
        // we've got a match
        var dataId = script.getAttribute('data-id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var attributeValue = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.scripts).filter(
     function(script){
         return script.src.indexOf('script.source.com/big/') > -1;
     })[0].attributes["atrributeName"].value;
```

where script tag is `<sript src="www.script.source.com/big/dud/baa.js" atrributeName="some value"><script>`

Answer (score 1):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); // load into a variable all the scripts of the page
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) { // parse all scripts
        var script = scripts[i];
        if (script.getAttribute('src') == '//example.com/embed.js') {
            alert(script.dataset.id); // Show only specified script
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to explain _why_ your code answers the question with a brief (or even better, detailed) explanation.