# JS Get script parameters from inside?

Tags: javascript

I have a script "myscript.js" which I'm embedding like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" data-param="{'param1':true,'param2':false}"></script>
```

How can I get the value of `data-param` inside of myscript.js? I would prefer to do this without jQuery.

PS. I once saw something like this: `<script src="myscript.js,param3">` - how would I get `param3` if I did this?

Comment: You could add an ID to your script tag, and use the normal document or JQuery selector approach

Comment: Maybe this answare can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data attribute of script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var param = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].getAttribute("data-param");
```

This assumes you only have 1 script (hence the `[0]`) -- if you have more, well, you'll have to loop and get the right value.

Comment: You'd also want to use something like `JSON.parse(param)` if you want to treat that value as an object, and you'd have to use double quotes: `data-param="{\"param1\":true,\"param2\":false}"`. Single quotes around keys are not valid JSON and will not parse.

Comment: What in case of more then one script ? possible scripts before and after ?

Comment: If you can assign IDs to your scripts: `<script id="script1">`, then you can use `document.getElementByID('script1')` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]`.

Comment: Well, do you know what value you're going for?

Answer (score 0):

Get the last script element in the page and use `getAttribute` to get the parameters. The last script element is always the current one, so you don't need to work with IDs.

```
// Get all script tags
var scriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
// Get the number of scripts
var numberOfScripts = scriptElements.length;
// The current script is the last script in the list
var currentScript = scriptElements[numberOfScripts - 1];
// Now you can retrieve the attribute
var param = JSON.parse(currentScript.getAttribute("data-param"));
```

This is the same, only shorter and less readable:

```
var scriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var param = JSON.parse(scriptElements[scriptElements.length - 1].getAttribute("data-param"));
```