# How do I read JS as data from a script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a external file (let's say foo.js)

```
function baz() {}
```

Then in my HTML, I import it with the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
```

I want to be able to get a string of the JS from inside of the script tag. I have tried jquery's html(), and the innerHTML and innerText attributes, but they all return empty strings.

Note: I am trying to avoid AJAX, because my server is slow, and to decrease the size of the webpage, even with caches.

Edit:
The string I want to get would contain the data in the javascript file, not its URL:

```
getJsData(document.querySelector('script[src="foo.js"]')) == 'function baz() {}'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to be able to get a string of the JS from inside of the script tag.`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag , well look over the link, the first answer might provide some insights, though not the answer to your exact question. As providing an `id` to script tags was new to me as well.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: may be you can do this by ajax call  check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag

Comment: @mailmindlin, your code works before or after page load?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no performance differences between an external script tag or an ajax call to the same uri for the web server. Both can be cached by the browser and will not hit the server if caching headers were properly set. Using an iframe instead will not ease server load either and causes quite some code clutter, so imho you really should go the ajax way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not exactly understand what is it and why you want to implement this. Considering that you do not want to use `ajax` due to *slow server issues*, you might as well do it old school.
If your page is not very heavy, you can  -

- Put a *hidden* `iframe` on the page pointing its src to your JS file.
- Wait for the `$('document').ready()` to be called inside the iframe, i.e. let the iFrame load all the content.
- Copy the contents of the iframe one its loaded into the HTML element container you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, this can be done without the need for `iframes` or `ajax`.

Since your external function is available to you; simply just invoke `toString()` on it. eg:

```
window.console.log(baz.toString());
```

Here is an example that demonstrates a *typical valid reason* for wanting to do this kind of thing & also it's limitations:

```js
var strMod=GameOfLife.toString();

//real shenzi prettification lol
(strMod.indexOf(";var")>-1) && (strMod=strMod.replace(/;/g, ";\t\n"));

var nodeCtr=document.getElementById('code-block');    
var nodeCodes=document.createElement("pre");
nodeCodes.classList.add("code-snippet");
nodeCtr.appendChild(nodeCodes);
nodeCodes.innerHTML="var GameOfLife="+strMod;

SyntaxHighlighter.highlight({brush: "js"}, nodeCodes);
```

```css
body
{
    background-color:#131313;
}

a:link,
a:visited
{
    color: rgba(185, 176, 218, 0.78);
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus
{
    color: rgba(41, 129, 241, 0.78);
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#code-block
{
    max-width:800px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#code-block .syntaxhighlighter
{
    margin:20px;
    font-size:10px!important;
    overflow:visible!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/styles/shCore.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/styles/shThemeEmacs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nomatteus/conway-game-of-life-js/master/gameoflife.js"></script>


<a href="https://github.com/nomatteus/conway-game-of-life-js">
    Conways Game of Life ~ js-stylee! ~ by Matthew Ruten
</a>

<div id="code-block"></div>
```

[&fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/ga8yLnsg/)

As can be seen; in some browsers, this particular usage is going to work more or less well, depending upon the `toString()` implementation. -all of which is discussed in [this nice little article](http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/)

**Another caveat:** this trick also won't work so well on `Objects` that are not functions or functions that immediately execute (ie: `RMP`) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id in the script tag and get that element from a jQuery selector like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="my_id" src="foo.js"></script>
```

```html
<script>
  var my_js_file = $("#my_id").attr("src");
  my_js_file.trim(".js");
</script>
```