# How to get argument from self loaded script inside the script itself

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this example

```
<script src="https://example.com/init.js?v=1589383111"></script>
```

How i get Argument v inside the init.js script

init.js script

```
var version = v; // argument from the src itself
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about your problem? As it is, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve and how you've attempted to do it.

Comment: I use an asset minifier with CSP enabled that does not allow inline script and ii want to pass a variable that is already configured by PHP to the minified script.
But i dont want to enable inline script

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the current script tag with `document.currentScript`. Then its a simple matter of extracting the `src` attribute, and parsing it as a URL.

```html
<!-- _src is used simply for demo purpose. You can't have a src attribute on a script tag with a body -->
<script _src="https://example.com/init.js?v=1589383111">
  const self = document.currentScript;
  const v = new URLSearchParams(
    new URL(self.getAttribute('_src')).search,
  ).get('v');
  
  console.log(v);
</script>
```

Comment: nice, i understood the question differently but this is more likely what the OP was asking...

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider putting the version in a data attribute on the backend, along with an  ID. Then you can access them from the DOM:

```
<script src="https://example.com/init.js?v=1589383111" 
    data-version="1589383111"
    id="importantScript"></script>
```

Now you can get the value of that attribute:

```
const version = document.getElementById('importantScript').getAttribute('data-version');
```

Answer (score 1):

From within the script:

```
const curScriptElement = document.currentScript;
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(curScriptElement.src).search);
const version = queryParams.get('v');
console.log('version is', version);
```

See demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/vd02AYWHnJhY6eu1

In this case, mind the browser support (IE specifically):

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=document-currentscript
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Answer (score -1):

look at `URL` and `URLSearchParams` -

```js
const u =
  new URL('https://example.com/init.js?v=1589383111')
  
const s =
  new URLSearchParams(u.search)
  
console.log(s.get("v"))
// 1589383111
```

Comment: How would that URL value be available from the init function in the file?

Comment: @isherwood if `https://example.com/init.js` is the homepage of the app...

Comment: I don't understand. You're passing it as a magic string. Where does that come from? It's a dynamic value.

Comment: isherwood, i was imagining the `init.js` as the entry point to a single-page app or something. in my mind, the question was more about getting the value out of the string, and less about how to get the actual url. there's a variety of ways to do that...