# Adding analytics tracking code to my websites

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics, analytics, matomo

I want to change how I embed the Matomo (https://matomo.org/) tracking code to my website.

I am using self-hosted version of Matomo to track a few websites, and every single time I need to change tracking options I have to manually update them on all the websites.

Is it possible for me to have a central file so that I can embed that on all websites. This way when I need to make any changes, I have to change it in just one file and it will get auto reflected on all my websites.

**Currently, I have to insert the tracking code like this:**

```
<!-- Matomo -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//example.com/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 'SITE-ID-OF-INDIVIDUAL-WEBSITE']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- End Matomo Code -->
```

**Instead, I want to do something like this:**

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js" data-site="INDIVIDUAL-SITE-IDENTIFIER" defer></script>
```

- or -

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js" data-site="INDIVIDUAL-SITE-IDENTIFIER" async></script>
```

Comment: what is preventing you to do so?

Comment: This seems related to, or even a duplicate of, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag

Comment: Or in your tracking script file, you keep an object that maps tracking ids to domain names, and just match the current url with that object. Then you would not need a data attribute.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Can you give me an example of how to do that so that I can read up on it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but frot the gist of it, you can use env variables.